# Process gets killed instead of except block executed

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, try-except

I am working on a project and need to compute distance matrices between data. Since the computational resources I am given are not big, I'm doing loops with increasing sizes of data and use a `try...except` yet the behavior is not as intended:

Minimal, reproducible example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

for samples in range(20000,60001,10000):
    print("SAMPLES: "+str(samples))
    X = np.random.random(size=(samples,100)).astype(np.float64)
    try:
        dissmat = pairwise_distances(X,metric="euclidean")
    except MemoryError:
        print("Not enough memory for distance matrix.")
    else:
        print("This runs if the exception was not raised")
```

Output I get:

```
python3 my_program.py

SAMPLES: 20000
This runs if the exception was not raised
SAMPLES: 30000
This runs if the exception was not raised
SAMPLES: 40000
This runs if the exception was not raised
SAMPLES: 50000
Killed
```

Expected behavior:

```
python3 my_program.py

SAMPLES: 20000
This runs if the exception was not raised
SAMPLES: 30000
This runs if the exception was not raised
SAMPLES: 40000
This runs if the exception was not raised
SAMPLES: 50000
Not enough memory for distance matrix.
SAMPLES: 60000
Not enough memory for distance matrix.
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

I have been doing some experiments and I guess the problem comes from how the size of the data is created.
Creating a matrix that is always bigger than support (thus ignoring the loop sizes) gets the desired behavior. Yet, keeping the "number of samples" variable with the value in range, doesn't.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances


for samples in range(5):
    print("SAMPLES: "+str(samples))
    X = np.random.random(size=(60000,1250))
    try:
        dis = pairwise_distances(X)

    except MemoryError as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print("Not enough memory for distance matrix.")
    else:
        print("This runs if the exception was not raised")
```

Output:

```
Unexpected err=MemoryError((60000, 60000), dtype('float64')), type(err)=<class 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError'>
Not enough memory for distance matrix.
Unexpected err=MemoryError((60000, 60000), dtype('float64')), type(err)=<class 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError'>
Not enough memory for distance matrix.
Unexpected err=MemoryError((60000, 60000), dtype('float64')), type(err)=<class 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError'>
Not enough memory for distance matrix.
Unexpected err=MemoryError((60000, 60000), dtype('float64')), type(err)=<class 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError'>
Not enough memory for distance matrix.
```

**update 2**

So, after some more testing I realize that the process gets killed because of the resources not being sufficient to do the computations of the matrix, not because the matrix wouldn't fit in memory. As seen in the previous example, when Python "knows" it won't be able to handle the matrix on ram, the error gets raised. However, as in the first code-block, Python thinks it can allocated the memory for the matrix so it begins the computations of the distance matrix, but it can't really handle it, and the process gets killed.